# How to get input value in TypeScript (ember)?

Tags: typescript, ember.js

I am new to Ember, try to make simple todo app by my own after YT tutorial. However I have a problem when I try to access input value.

> Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'

My function:

```
updateNewItemValue(event: InputEvent) {
    this.newItem = event!.target.value;
 }
```

Using it in template:

```
<input
    type='text'
    {{on 'input' this.updateNewItemValue}}
    value={{this.newItem}}
/>
```

Maybe am I using wrong type for **event** argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Typescript, it doesn't know what sort of element the event will be coming from. So what I like to do is *assert* that the element is correct.

This has the advantage of providing a clear message to developers when they mis-configure something.

Additionally, `assert` is removed in production builds.

```js
import { assert } from '@ember/debug';

// ...

updateNewItemValue(event: Event) {
  assert(
    `Expected input event handler to be used an an 'input' element,` + 
    ` instead received: ${event.target.tagName}.`,
    event.target instanceof HTMLInputElement
  );

  this.newItem = event.target.value;
}
```